# duplicate pic in mousemottion

Tags: python, pygame

I try to drag an image after it is clicked, but when I do, the image is duplicated. How do I fix the code so that when I drag the image, it won't duplicate

```
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 200 < mouse_point[0] < 550 and 475 < mouse_point[1] < 568:
            if turn == 0:
                onMouseCards = True
                clickedCard = find_card(player1, mouse_point)
            else:
                onMouseCards = True
                clickedCard = find_card(player1, mouse_point)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and onMouseCards:
            posx = event.pos[0]
            posy = event.pos[1]
            screen.blit(pic, [posx, posy])
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You have to clear the screen in every frame. e.g. `screen.fill(0)` (before the event handling).

Comment: Where should I put screen.fill(0) ? When I insert it, it turns the screen black and deletes all the background, and I need the image to move but the background will probably remain

Comment: You have to draw the background in every frame (you have to draw the entire scene in every frame). It is not possible to "move" an image. You can just draw an image on top of the scene. The snippet in your question is not complete. `screen.fill(0)` was just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

in the main part of your game loop before events

```
while True: #game loop
    screen.fill(0)
    for event in pg.event.get():
    ...
```